How to connect local pgadmin to a remote docker/postgres
Prostgres db is running in docker on a VPS (Ubuntu).
docker ps
4f945e0bf0bc postgres "docker-entrypoint.s…" 2 hours ago Up 2 hours 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp postgres-0

From a Windows PC, I want to connect to the database using pgadmin, but it's not successfull :
Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired.
In the "Host name/address" field of pgadmin I've entered the IP address of the Ubuntu server.
See output of command "ip a"
What else do I need to configure so that pgadmin can access the DB ?



you need a composer file that sets the ports and the dockerdesktop must also add the ports

connection timeout usually means there is a firewall blocking the connection.

There is no firewall installed on the server

The postgres port "5432" has been exposed. See the output iof the command "docker ps" :    5432->5432.   What else could a docker compose file achieve ?

I used the wrong password. All is working fine and the setup is correct
